# Python: Logging handler only log level log less than ERROR

Tags: python

I need a way for a python logger to not log ERROR or above. Need it to only log less than ERROR.

```
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler

def get_log_formatter():
    datefmt = '%b %d %y %H:%M:%S'
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(module)s:%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
                          datefmt=datefmt)
    return formatter

class MyHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, max_level, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.max_level = max_level
    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelno >= self.max_level:
            return
        return super(MyHandler, self).emit(record)

handl = MyHandler(logging.ERROR)
handl.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handl.setFormatter(get_log_formatter())
logger = logging.getLogger("testing_logger")
logger.addHandler(handl)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This seems to work, but does it make sense? Is there a better way to filter out the logline?

```
In [3]: logger_num = 0

In [4]: logger = remake()

In [5]: logger.info("Why")
May 16 01 16:50:10 [<ipython-input-5-c350362291ad>:INFO] Why

In [6]: logger.warn("Why")
May 16 01 16:50:13 [<ipython-input-6-56809439d5a4>:WARNING] Why

In [7]: logger.error("Why")

In [8]:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw back of your solution is that you'd have to subclass every handler you'd like to use.

A context filter is much clearer in it's intent:

```
class MaxFilter:
    def __init__(self, max_level):
        self.max_level = max_level

    def filter(self, record):
        if record.levelno < self.max_level:
            return True
```

And can be applied to any handler as such:

```
any_concrete_handler.addFilter(MaxFilter(logging.INFO))
```